# Enviar un dato del Listbox de un formulario a un Textbox de otro formulario

Tags: excel, vba

He logrado pasar un dato seleccionado del Listbox1 de un Form1 a un Textbox1 de un Form2 con el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub btnModificar_Click()
If Me.Listbox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
    MsgBox "No se ha elegido ningún registro",
Else
   Dim DATO As String, I As Integer
        DATO = Listbox1.Text
        I = Listbox1.ListIndex
        If Listbox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
        UserForm2.Textbox1.Text = DATO
        End If

   UserForm2.Show
End If
End Sub

Sin embargo; mi problema es que cuando puse el Initialize en el UseForm2

Private Sub UserForm2_Initialize()
End Sub
```

me aparece el Error de "Se requiere un objeto", que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué linea te destaca cuando da el error? De todas formas, quizás deberías llevarte el valor de DATO a una variable pública y entonces cargarlo en el USerform2

Comment: probaré con la variable publica gracias